# Tampermonkey script is probably executed at the wrong time

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I want to make a script that fills the registration form for Doulos webinars. e.g. https://register.gotowebinar.com/register/2965111702634965004

When I go to this link via Firefox it loads https://register.gotowebinar.com/pageNotFound

Only when I click back then the proper form comes in. It looks like tampermonkey is trying to run the script before it gets to the right form, it doesn't find the right fields there and in this situation once it loads the fields indicated in the script are not filled in.

Here an example if I wanted to fill the first name and email:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Duolos autofill registration form
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       blaz
// @match        https://register.gotowebinar.com/register/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=gotowebinar.com
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==

    var formFirstName = document.getElementById('registrant.firstName')
    var formEmail = document.getElementById('registrant.email')

    formFirstName.value = 'My_first_name'
    formEmail.value = 'my@email.com'
```

Important note: this is my first contact with JavaScript and Tampermonkey.

How to make such a script properly?

Comment: I believe the page needs some time to build and render, and your script indeed runs too early, when the page is not yet rendrerd. Try to delay your script a little bit with `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 0):

Filling works as I applied the suggested setTimeout() by @JeremyThille

I keep up with clicking on 'Undo' within 10 seconds and the form loads during that time.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("10s later...");

    var formFirstName = document.getElementById('registrant.firstName')
    var formEmail = document.getElementById('registrant.email')

    formFirstName.value = 'My_first_name'
    formEmail.value = 'my@email.com'

}, 10000);
```